# Get wrapper DOM element attributes from a method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a link in a React component:

```
<a href="#goals-tab" className={ this.setTabStyle()}>Goals</a>
```

Now, inside `setTabStyle` method, can I access attributes of the `a` element, like `href` without explicitly passing it to the method as a parameter?

Comment: I don't know this React, but without using it, you can make a function out that get or edit the element attrs (with [element].getAttribute([attr]) and setAttribute([attr],[value])).

Comment: `function getClass(e,c){return e.getAttribute(c);}`

Comment: `<a href="#goals-tab" onload="getClass(this,'href')">Goals</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a ref, then your component renders DOM *without* the styles, and then applies the new styles. So the user will notice the change of styles.

I would advise to pass link as a parameter to `setTabStyle(link)`, or make the link another prop of your component:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function (e) {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('href'));
    },

    setTabStyle: function () {
        if (this.props.link == this.props.activelink) {
            return myActiveLinkStyle
        } else {
            return myInactiveLinkStyle
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return <a href={this.props.link} style={this.setTabStyle()} onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</a>;
    }
});
```

That way, you get the right style from the initial load..